# Como atribuir valor a letras de uma palavra

Tags: python

Quero entrar com uma palavra (str). Ex.: "Curitiba"
Depois quero baseado em uma tabela de valores, atribuir valor (Int) a cada letra dessa entrada. Ex.: Curitiba--> "C"=1, "U"=2, "R"=4... etc
Após transformado a entrada em valores quero fazer operações matemáticas, tipo soma 1+2+4....=7

Revirei a internet e não achei! Como posso fazer isso?

Achei no forum o seguinte, que separa cada letra de "Teste"

```
lista = ['teste', 'teste', 'teste', 'teste', 'teste']

matriz = []

for palavra in lista:
    matriz.append(list(palavra))

print(matriz)
```

output:

```
[['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e'], ['t', 'e', 's', 't', 'e']]
```

Feito isso ou algo como isso, quero dar um valor (int) pre estabelecido para cada letra, por exemplo "T"=1, "E"=2, "S"=3....

E após isso somar os valores.

Em resumo:

- Entrar com um nome. Ex.: Curitiba
- Separar as letras dessa entrada. Ex.: C, U, R, I, T, I, B, A
- Atribuir uma valor inteiro a cada uma dessas letras. Ex.: C=1, U=2...
- Pode fazer operações com esses valores. Ex.: 1(C)+2(U) = 3
- A saída da informação será por exemplo: 'CURITIBA' = 100

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Felipe, melhorei a questão, veja se consegui me fazer entender!

Comment: Não ficou muito claro quais valores você quer atribuir a cada letra da palavra, é uma tabela padronizada ou cada letra recebe o valor da anterior +1?

Comment: Felipe o valor atrabuido a cada letra é de uma tabela pre estabelecida.

Comment: E o resultado seria uma lista com cada letra da palavra e sua soma?

Comment: O Resultado seria por exemplo: "ABC" A=1, B=2, C=3. Resultado seria 1+2+3=6 ou ABC = 6

Comment: Digo, o retorno que você quer seria somente um texto contendo a palavra junto da soma? Por exemplo: palavra = "ABC", Resultado: "ABC = 6".

Comment: Felipe o retorno seria numérico: "ABC"=6. Valor final precisa ser numérico (int)

Comment: Acho que entendi do que precisa, acrescentei como resposta.

Comment: @FelipeGambini ou o Autor da pergunta: Favor [editar] a pergunta e incluir a informação consensualizada nos comentários, pois da maneira que se encontram pergunta e respostas são discordantes.

Answer (score -1):

Para chegar no resultado do problema apresentado, primeiro criei uma variável com um dicionário classificando todas as letras do alfabeto e atribuindo um número a cada uma:

```
valores = {' ':0,'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26}
```

Então criei o código:

```
lista = ['Curitiba', 'Fortaleza', 'Salvador']  # Lista que receberá as palavras desejadas

for palavra in lista:
  soma = 0
  for letra in palavra:
    soma += valores[letra.lower()]
  print(f'{palavra}: {soma}')
```

O código percorre todas as palavras, cria uma variável `soma` que irá somar os números atribuídos às letras, percorrerá todas as letras da palavra e somará o respectivo valor da letra definido no dicionário `valores`.

Utilizei `letra.lower()` caso seja informado letras em maiúsculo, pois o dicionário está em letras minúsculas.

Resultado:

```
Curitiba: 83
Fortaleza: 104
Salvador: 92
```

Comment: Extamente isso Felipe!  Muito obrigado pela ajuda!